# Using 2 conditions with an IF statement in Cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, e2e-testing

Hello I'm trying to run the following code but somehow it does not work. The same code will work if I simply separate the IF statement in 2 and nest it.
My intention is to select only one element from the dropdown list but buy using includes, I'm getting 2 results; that is why I was trying to add an extra condition to it.

```
cy.get("#autocomplete").type("ne");
    cy.get(".ui-menu-item").each(($el) => {
      if ($el.text().includes("Netherlands" && $el.text().length === 11)) {       
        cy.wrap($el).click();
      }
```

Do you happen to know why that is? is there a better way of doing this? thank you

Comment: Just bracket out of place, should be `$el.text().includes("Netherlands") && $el.text().length === 11`. Or save some typing and use exact matching `$el.text() === "Netherlands"`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with a `.filter()` with a function parameter.

This variation is not currently in the Cypress docs, but they are using jQuery under the hood so refer here [jQuery docs, filter(function)](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function).

Note the function receives the raw DOM element so use `innerText` instead of jQuery `.text()`.

You can add multiple criteria, but with `===` it checks for an exact match and the length check isn't needed.

```js
cy.get("#autocomplete").type("ne");
cy.get('.ui-menu-item')                                   // all items
  .filter((index, el) => el.innerText === "Netherlands")  // precise match
  .eq(0)                                                  // take the first
  .click();                                               // select it
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `)` missing after the text Netherlands, you have to add that and there is an extra bracket `)` added after 11, you have to remove that. So, your code should be:

```
cy.get("#autocomplete").type("ne");
    cy.get(".ui-menu-item").each(($el) => {
      if ($el.text().includes("Netherlands") && $el.text().length === 11) {       
        cy.wrap($el).click();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar issue where I want to select an item in a custom select component (so not a native `select` element).

I used a derivation of the most upvoted answer to achieve this:

```
cy.get('my-component .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-option')
      .filter((_, el) => {
        return el.querySelector('span.badge-location')?.textContent === locationName
          && el.querySelector('span.platform-name')?.textContent === platformName;
      })
      .should('have.length', 1)
      .click();
```

The code loops through all possible option elements and finds the one I'm looking for and clicks on that one.